# How can in display Base_64 encode data into a screeen

Tags: php, codeigniter, base64

after a fetching base_64 encode from db i tried to display ......

```
{
    $img=$key->image;
    {
    $decode=base64_decode($img);
    if (write_file("assets/images/img.jpeg",$decode,"w+")) 

?>
        <img src="<?= base_url('assets/images/img.jpeg') ?>" width="70"height="70">
<?php
}
```

its fetching the data from db and decoded base_64 data but after all this its not viewing the image
please help //// thanks in advance

Comment: Your `{` I think should be part of the IF and not hanging around before the IF

Comment: sorry its my typing mistakes @RiggsFolly

Comment: So fix it so the question code is actually what you are running